# Measure Theory (Defining Measureability)

Tags: measure-theory

just a very basic measure theory question from the book by Bartle.

Let (a) be the statement "For every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, the set $A_\alpha=\{x\in X: f(x)>\alpha\}$ belongs to **X**." (X is a measurable space)

It is claimed that if (a) holds, then $A_{\alpha-1/n}$ belongs to **X** for each n.

Why is this so?

Comment: Because $\alpha-1/n\in\mathbb R$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Did remarks, $\alpha-1/n\in\mathbb{R}$, so $$A_{\alpha-1/n}=\{x\in X:f(x)>\alpha-1/n\}\in X.$$ Everything is well-defined. Kind of strange that they make this into an explicit claim.